# Jboss (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit]

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am facing below issues when I tried to deploy my war file in jboss 7.1.1 server.
Everytime when I try to deploy my war file, it gets rolled back

1. Missing/unsatisfied dependencies: service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources."ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."SAMWebService.war#SAMWebServicePU"]
2. Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"SAMWebService.war#SAMWebServicePU\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.\"ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]\"Missing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"SAMWebService.war#SAMWebServicePU\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.\"ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]\"]"]}}}

Please find below the jboss console

```
10:19:05,582 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-3) Creating Service {http://port.service.sam.sourcecode.rs/}SAMWebService from class rs.sourcecode.sam.service.port.SAMWebService
10:19:08,910 INFO  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-3) Setting the server's publish address to be http://localhost:8080/SAMWebService/SAMWebService
10:19:09,691 INFO  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.WSDLFilePublisher] (MSC service thread 1-3) WSDL published to: file:/D:/Project_Softwares/Servers/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/data/wsdl/SAMWebService.war/SAMWebService.wsdl
10:19:09,707 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015539: Starting service jboss.ws.port-component-link
10:19:09,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015539: Starting service jboss.ws.endpoint."SAMWebService.war"."rs.sourcecode.sam.service.port.SAMWebService"
10:19:09,863 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.DefaultEndpointRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-8) register: jboss.ws:context=SAMWebService,endpoint=rs.sourcecode.sam.service.port.SAMWebService
10:19:09,863 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
10:19:09,863 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 21265ms - Started 168 of 255 services (10 services failed or missing dependencies, 76 services are passive or on-demand)
10:19:10,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "SAMWebService.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"SAMWebService.war#SAMWebServicePU\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.\"ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]\"Missing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"SAMWebService.war#SAMWebServicePU\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.\"ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]\"]"]}
10:19:10,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015540: Stopping service jboss.ws.endpoint."SAMWebService.war"."rs.sourcecode.sam.service.port.SAMWebService"
10:19:10,285 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.DefaultEndpointRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-7) remove: jboss.ws:context=SAMWebService,endpoint=rs.sourcecode.sam.service.port.SAMWebService
10:19:10,347 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015540: Stopping service jboss.ws.port-component-link
10:19:29,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SAMWebService.war in 18801ms
10:19:29,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources."ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."SAMWebService.war#SAMWebServicePU"] 

10:19:29,097 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"SAMWebService.war#SAMWebServicePU\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.\"ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]\"Missing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"SAMWebService.war#SAMWebServicePU\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.\"ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]\"]"]}}}
```

Please find below my standalone.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
            <show-model value="true"/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
            <properties>
                <!-- Specifies the beginning start level of the framework -->
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">1</property>
            </properties>
            <capabilities>
                <!-- modules registered with the OSGi layer on startup -->
                <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
                <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                <!-- bundles started in startlevel 1 -->
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
            </capabilities>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
    </profile>
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <!--
              ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
              ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL 
              -->
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

Please find below peristence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SAMWebServicePU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Can anyone guide me on resolving this issue or give me any idea on how to proceed further ?

Comment: Could you share your app's `persistence.xml` ? I think it defines `ExampleDS [jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]` where it should only define `ExampleDS`

Comment: Hi @Aaron thanks for your response. I have updated my question now with  persistence.xml file. Please have a look and guide me. Thanks

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, that `[jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]` has nothing to do in the `<jta-data-source>` tag and should be removed

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aaron, my issue got resolved.  I removed this part "[jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1]"  in persistence.xml and tried deploying, now my war file got deployed.